# Prevent having nested v-containers in Vue project

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and started contributing to a project at my work. I have a reusable component that is wrapped in a v-container, so it is aligned when it's standing alone. However, I wish to use this component within another component that is also wrapped in a v-container. The problem is, when the reusable component is being used as a child component, it's basically being wrapped in v-container twice. Is there a smart way to solve this? Maybe wrap it in v-container conditionally somehow?

Comment: Why is this a problem ?

Comment: Because I don’t want to apply the padding of the v-container when it’s contained in another component that is encapsulated in a v-container.

Comment: Then do not wrap your component in `v-container` - leave this to it's parent component